# google-realtime-api - how to access all the objects in a file

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

So I am trying to add multiple objects to my google-realtime-api app. For example, I've got something like this:

```
function onFileInitialize (model) {
var collaborativeList = model.createList();
collaborativeList.pushAll(['Cat', 'Dog', 'Sheep']);
model.getRoot().set('demo_list', collaborativeList);

var collaborativeList2 = model.createList();
collaborativeList2.pushAll(['1', '2', '3']);
model.getRoot().set('demo_list2', collaborativeList2);
```

My question is how can I access them all at the same time? So it would be possible to render them and add event-listeners to them without having to do it separately by first getting 'demo_list' and then 'demo_list2' and repeating a lot of code.

Is it possible with realtime to do something like:

```
for (var i=0...) { doc.getModel().getRoot().get(i); };
```

?

Answer (score 0):

The root is a CollaborativeMap, so you can use getKeys or getValues to iterate through all the items.